# Trigger not fire

Tags: after-trigger

I have Case(Parent), Enquiries(child) objects. When Enquiries status is not equal to Processed then Case should not be closed. I have written trigger on child object. It's not working.

```
trigger t on Enquiries (after update) {
  set<id> ids=new set <id>();
  for(Enquiries ac : trigger.new){
     if(ac.status__c!='Processed'){
        ids.add(ac.id);
     }
  }
  List<Enquiries > enq =[select id,status from Enquiries where id in:ids];
  for(Enquiries c:enq){
     if(c.status=='Closed'){
        c.addError('coluld not closed');
        // updatecaseList.add(c);
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to stop Cases from being edited, you need a trigger on Case, not Enquiries.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, you should be writing all your code/functionality in a helper class, rather than in a trigger. That way its easy to maintain/test/less-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You will be not able to block a case to be closed if the trigger is beeing fired just on Enquires, your trigger should be created at Case level (before/after update).

Thanks